# Cleaning Code: Fresh Start vs Hardcore Cleaning

Tags: php, codeigniter

so I got a budget to clean up code that I've inherited from another programmer. the code is in really bad shape, there's lots of files not being used, there's lots of functions not being used. It actually looks like linear programming instead of object oriented. My issue is whether or not I should

a) Clean the code, restructure it, and try to delete all unused resources
b) start with a fresh framework (it's using codeigniter), and copy over the files that are needed to run

I like option b because it kind of reminds me of a new laptop from best buy. I can either spend the time removing all the bloatware or do a wipeout and create the system from scratch, which I always do. The only problem is that this time, there's a lot more involved then just creating a fresh system. Here are the pros and cons:

### PROS

- Clean system that is very easy to maintain
- Don't need to go around searching for unused files
- Easier to keep track of what I've done

### CONS

- Lots of things can break
- Might miss required files
- Might take longer

What do you think? Can you give me some of your pros and cons, and what you might do in a situation like this?

### Update

A lot of people say that I am missing an important part, budget (time and money). We do have a decent budget, but my project manager is willing to go over if it ensures a more solid system with quicker turnaround time for new features. It's hard for me to quantify budget because you have not seen code, so giving hours won't help which is why I did not say anything about budget. I guess from your prospective, consider this a budget that can accommodate both solutions.

Comment: A technical solution is dependent on a set of resources: time, knowledgebase and budget being the most important. And you didn't mention these.

Comment: *(tipp)* http://www.refactoring.com/sources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often a hybrid approach works better. Keep the gold nuggets and toss the rest. Most likely there is some really effective code even in the worst project. Also, things that would be painful to rewrite and already work well, you might just clean those up a little.

It takes a little judgment to determine what to keep, but you can kind of have the best of both that way.

Comment: Agreed. Such discernment takes practice, but this is the best approach. Even doing this, you will still have to make a that project-level decision as whether or not to "start over" though. Fun, fun.

Comment: This is actually the approach that I am leaning towards. I will search through the old code, and take out the good stuff and put it into my new codeigniter installation. Fill in missing blanks and hopefully I should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning someone else's code can be a nightmare. If you can actually choose and the stakeholders agree, I'd strongly recommend you to start over.

I had an experience like this last year and to this date, the software is still in pretty bad shape, it's almost impossible to track every mistake made by the programmers we inherited the code from and spend a LOT of time on support for hidden bugs and stuff.

Comment: I'm dealing with this right now. Except for all the bad code I fix/clean/overhaul, more bad code is produced. I may or may not be slowly losing my mind.

Comment: Yes, it can be a nightmare. Hang in there, though I myself have lost all hope that we're ever gonna get there. Stakeholders have also spent so much money on the old system that we could have already built it again twice. In our case, we kept recommending a fresh start but they never agreed :( ...

Comment: That can be tricky. From the outside, "it already mostly works". But when you're thrown onto a project like described above, you quickly find out otherwise. Come to think of it, almost all projects I've been pulled into are like that :-/

Comment: Im actually sorry to hear that =/

Answer (score 2):

I guess it somewhat depends on your time constraints and how intimately you'll need to know the project.

I just finished restructuring some code written by a math-majoring grad student. Bright guy, but he's not a programmer and the code was, as you said, very linear. Long story short, I rewrote about 90% of the code and took more time doing it than I would have liked. **It would have been faster for me to start from scratch**, using his code as a reference. Not only that, if I had planned on making as many changes as I had, **I would have put more thought into the restructuring process.** On the bright side, I now know all the code and concepts in this project very well.

On the other hand, if you don't plan on making many changes or having to maintain the code, maybe it's not worth the hassle. Get it to a usable state and tuck in back under the rug, so to speak.

My 2 cents...

Comment: I will be building on top of this code. After this clean up, there's going to be a lot of features coming.

Answer (score 2):

This question reminds me of Joel's article I've read a while back.

> The single worst strategic mistake
>   that any software company can make:
>   They decided to rewrite the code from
>   scratch... It’s harder to read code than
>   to write it.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: Well, I think that article needs qualification.  It's the worst strategic mistake as long as the software meets operational requirements.  And those requirements change dramatically over time.  So if a codebase can't meet today's requirements because it's so ill-aligned and/or poor quality, then you can't realistically refactor it without throwing it away...  So while it's true when you have a working application that was built with a reasonable architecture, there are plenty of cases where the architecture is **so** fubar that the only sane solution is to throw it away...

Comment: That was actually a really interesting article, and gets me to think about what I am doing. The reason why "I" think it's a mess is because there's code EVERYWHERE. We were supposed to have all SQL functions inside the model files, but they somehow started to seep into the controller files, there's huge calculations in view files, there are multiple functions that do the exact same thing and there is multiple lines of code that do the exact same thing (linear style). I will keep all the logic though, so it's not a full rewrite, but I will have to do lots of merging

Comment: Actually @Johnathan, it sounds like you just need a refactor rather than a rewrite.  If the application is already split out into multiple classes (even if the delimitation isn't enforced), you should be able to refactor a lot of it in place...  Sure it may be hard, but if you're only moving things around and adding or removing a few classes, it's not that difficult.  The fubar cases I was talking about typically involve 15k line functions, really bad variable names (REALLY bad), 15 copies of functions that don't even do what the name suggests, etc...

Comment: well actually, I am dealing with functions that don't do what they're supposed to and huge lines of code. There's a php file that's almost 15 MB of code. It's just random functions on the site, and I don't know if I need all of them or not. I guess a re-write was not the write choice of words. It was more a move over of the most vital pieces of code that I need, clean it up and put it into a new installation of codeigniter without the bloatcode. Is that considered a rewrite? I'm not even sure sometimes because I've never had the opportunity to do something like this.